# how to include springboot autogenerated endpoints in openapi.json

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, spring-boot-actuator, openapi-generator, health-check

we are using some of the springboot provided endpoints like `info,health,prometheus,metrics,beans,loggers`

Now, we add all of our endpoints in openapi.yml for our "API first" approach. So, we will update our openapi.yml files first and that would generated all our controllers structure.

But in case of autogenerated endpoints, how should we proceed. If we add the endpoints in openapi.yml, then that would generate the controllers for these endpoints as well.

So, how to handle such case where we have our custom endpoints as well as springboot provided endpoints. And we want to maintain all our endpoints in openapi.yml.

Comment: Does `.openapi-generator-ignore` as shown in this repo solve your problem?https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-petstore

Comment: Do you intend to display the endpoints in the generated yaml, and thusly on your swagger-ui page?  Remember that your openapi and the swagger-ui page are primarily documentation tools.  How do you intend to document these end-points?  Are these end-points consumer facing?  Remember that [`Spring Actuator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html) enabled endpoints are primarily administrative tools.  Not everything has to be in user documentation.